# OpenMATLAB[] hangs

Tags: warning-messages, interoperability, matlink

I just migrated my Mac from one machine to a new one and it seems like MATLink is broken now. When I call `OpenMATLAB[]` in Mathematica the command hangs forever.

I ran engine.sh, as instructed in the troubleshooting, but do not get any library errors (it just says Create Link :).

I tried reinstalling matlab and redownloaded MATlink.

`` MATLink`Developer`GetInfo[] `` Output:

```
MATLink 1.1 for MacOSX (Fri 15 Aug 2014)

11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)

csh:
/bin/csh

MATLAB:
/Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app
/Applications/MATLAB_R2017a.app
/Applications/MATLAB_R2018b.app
```

Comment: 1. Did you try restarting Mathematica completely? 2. Does MATLAB work when started separately? 3. Can you try running `ConnectEngine[]` after loading MATLink?  Does it hang? If not, try `OpenMATLAB[]` now. 4. When you evaluate `OpenMATLAB[]`, do you notice a MATLAB icon bounding in the dock?

Comment: 1. yes 2. Yes. 3. Hangs as well 4. No icon

Comment: This is going to take some back and forth. Please join this chatroom and continue there: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85499/matlink

Comment: I have not heard back from you. Did you resolve this already and can we close the question?

Comment: I commented back. Your solution works but how can I implement it?